# Generic way to handle nested objects in Spring Data R2DBC

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-data-r2dbc

In my Spring Boot Webflux project, I'm using Spring Data R2DBC for reactive data access. The project involves fetching data from a relational database, where some tables have columns containing JSON data that represent nested objects.

My current approach is to fetch the data and then manually parse the JSON into my POJO using custom read converters. However, this process becomes cumbersome when I have multiple nested objects and differing structures.

Here's a simplified example of what I've been doing:

```java
@UtilityClass
public class ConverterHelper {
    // ObjectMapper initialization

    public static <T> T readJson(Row row, String field, Class<T> clazz) {
        // implementation
    }
}

@ReadingConverter
public class CustomReadingConverter implements Converter<String, Object> {
    // implementation
}

@Configuration
public class R2dbcConfiguration extends AbstractR2dbcConfiguration {
    // implementation
}
```

The question I have is: Is there a more generic way to handle this, similar to how Spring Data JPA automatically maps nested objects? I'd prefer not to write custom converters every time I encounter this situation.

I understand that JPA or Hibernate might handle these scenarios more gracefully, but those aren't suitable for my project as I need the non-blocking I/O provided by R2DBC. Is there a solution to this in the realm of Spring Data R2DBC, or am I confined to using custom converters for these complex/nested objects?

Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this in another way by using a json field and then converting to whatever object I needed in a mapping step.

For example, I might have an entity like this:

```
import io.r2dbc.postgresql.codec.Json;

@Table("table_name")
@Data
@Builder
public class MyObject {
    @Id
    private Integer id;
    private Json data;
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;
    private LocalDateTime updatedAt;
}
```

With a DTO class like

```
@Data
@Builder
public class MyObjectDTO {
    private Integer id;
    private YourNestedObjectType data;
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;
    private LocalDateTime updatedAt;
}
```

And then a mapping class that does something like this:

```
public MyObjectDTO to(MyObject myObj) {
    try {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = 
        YourNestedObjectType somethingNested = objectMapper.readValue(
            myObj.getData().asString(), 
            YourNestedObjectType.class);

        return MyObjectDTO.builder()
                .id(myObj.getId())
                .data(somethingNested)
                .createdAt(myObj.getCreatedAt())
                .updatedAt(myObj.getUpdatedAt())
                .build();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

with the understanding that YourNestedObjectType can be a wrapper class that holds other classes like

```
public class YourNestedObjectType {
   private String field1;
   private List<OtherObject> otherObjects;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Initially, I tried to create a universal converter by customizing a generic type in Converter, but it didn't work (probably because of generic type erasure, which prevented Spring from reading the type information).
After some experimentation, I found that `GenericConverter` could fulfill our requirements.
Here is the code:

```java
@WritingConverter
public static class JsonWritingConverter implements GenericConverter {
    private final Set<ConvertiblePair> convertibleTypes;

    public JsonWritingConverter(Set<Class<?>> jsonTypes) {
        this.convertibleTypes = new HashSet<>();
        for (Class<?> targetType : jsonTypes) {
            this.convertibleTypes.add(new ConvertiblePair(targetType, Json.class));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Set<ConvertiblePair> getConvertibleTypes() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(convertibleTypes);
    }

    @Override
    public Object convert(Object source, TypeDescriptor sourceType, TypeDescriptor targetType) {
        return Json.of(JSON.toJSONString(source));
    }
}
```

```java
@ReadingConverter
public static class JsonReadingConverter implements GenericConverter {
    private final Set<ConvertiblePair> convertibleTypes;

    public JsonReadingConverter(Set<Class<?>> jsonTypes) {
        this.convertibleTypes = new HashSet<>();
        for (Class<?> targetType : jsonTypes) {
            this.convertibleTypes.add(new ConvertiblePair(Json.class, targetType));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Set<ConvertiblePair> getConvertibleTypes() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(convertibleTypes);
    }

    @Override
    public Object convert(Object source, TypeDescriptor sourceType, TypeDescriptor targetType) {
            Json jsonSource = (Json) source;
            return JSON.parseObject(jsonSource.asString(), targetType.getType());
    }
}
```

It can specify multiple `Source` and `Target` type combinations explicitly through the `Class<?>` by overriding the `getConvertibleTypes` method. This is much more reliable than using generics.
Then, you can write the conversion logic for the previously specified combinations inside the `convert` method.

As for registration, it's pretty much the same as with `Converter`.

```java
@Bean
public R2dbcCustomConversions r2dbcCustomConversions(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    List<Object> converters = new ArrayList<>();
    Reflections reflections = new Reflections("your.package.to.scan");
    Set<Class<?>> jsonTypes = reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(StoreJson.class);
    converters.add(new JsonConverter.JsonWritingConverter(jsonTypes));
    converters.add(new JsonConverter.JsonReadingConverter(jsonTypes));
    return R2dbcCustomConversions.of(DialectResolver.getDialect(connectionFactory), converters);
}
```

I used `Reflections` to scan for custom annotations, which allowed me to obtain all the classes mapped to custom Json in one go.
Moreover, since `Converter` and `ConvertiblePair` do not have an inheritance relationship, the generic type for `List<Object>` needs to be Object.
With this configuration, you only need to annotate your classes like this:

```java
@Data
@Builder
@StoreJson
public class SessionData {
    private List<SessionDataItem> itemData;
}
```

And it will work properly.

However, as you can see, I don't know how to gracefully handle the types of JSON arrays, and can only implement them through nested objects.
I hope my answer can help you and others.